# How to use multiple EditBox in alert dialogue

Tags: android

I want to use multiple Edit Text in an Alert dialog and the input should be filled by user and the information should be saved after clicking OK button of the Alert message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate layout for this alert that contains all Edit Text and use it.

Comment: Seperate layout or seperate xml in layout.Please distinguish.